# Windows Lower Filter Driver

Tags: filter, driver, wdk

Have some special USB drives whose Oxford Semi controllers are proclaiming themselves non-removable and I need to make them removable [which of course they are]. Oxford will not cooperate. Took Hitachi's cfadisk.c, tweaked the QueryPropertyCompletion function to confirm that the vendor ID was the one I'm looking for, then set the removable property before returning. Used DDK's addfilter to insert a lower filter for one of my special USB devices. addfilter listdevices showed the lower filter properly installed. Rebooted. Now special USB device no longer shows up; Windows Explorer doesn't see it. addfilter of course cannot be used to remove the lower filter because the device has to be there in the first place. Hunted down all references to my filter driver in the registry, but regedt32 declines to remove "LowerFilter" references that specify my driver. I even renamed the folder where my driver was found, rebooted, but regedt32 still declines to remove the references. How to convince Windows to let go of the lower filter driver? And I guess I'll have to setup a kernel debugger to find out what the filter driver is doing. Thanks.

Comment: Have written a program to search for registry values and then optionally delete them, just like REGEDT32.EXE, except my program gives the full error code and string if a delete failure occurs. Upon finding a LowerFilter with my driver name, failure is code 5, access denied. This is using an administrator privileged account, and a DOS window "run as administrator". Have also had a fellow with domain administrator rights attempt the same, and see same failure.

Comment: Right click on the key.  What are the permission settings?

Comment: LowerFilters is of course a value without permissions. The key above LowerFilters for Everyone only allows Read, for Owner only allows Special and for System allows FullControl and Read. This is Win7 and I am logged in with an account that is member of admin group. Have also had system admin login on same system with admin domain rights with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission settings you describe in your comments wouldn't allow anyone other than the SYSTEM account and perhaps the owner to delete it.  Logging in as an admin wouldn't matter unless that admin was also the owner *and* owner permissions allow delete, which is apparently not the case on your machine.

Every key on my machine (Win7) that contains a LowerFilters value gives full control to administrators, which means I could delete them.  So the only way you're going to delete or modify those values is to give full control to administrators on those keys.  How they came to not have full control, I can't say.

Comment: Apparently the security policies of my customer are so convoluted that admin privileged accounts cannot manipulate registry entries, which is why on right clicking the key I see Everyone, Owner and System but not Administrators. No amount of prodding regedt32 succeeds in getting Administrators to appear in the list. I've requested a separate desktop system without company security policies implemented to develop and test the filter driver. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that's a really absurd policy.  Sounds like it would make the machine almost unmanageable.